# GEE: How can I code this more simply?

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript

I want to make a long-term period selector and need more selectors, not just one.
So, I made each label and value in items and copied them.
I want to know if there is a more efficient method.
Please, tell me the simple way.

```
var select1 = ui.Select({
  
  items: [{label: '------------------', value: 'none'}, {label: '1990', value: 0},
    {label: '1901', value: 1}, {label: '1902', value: 2}, {label: '1903', value: 3},{label: '1904', value: 4},{label: '1905', value: 5},
    {label: '1906', value: 6}, {label: '1907', value: 7}, {label: '1908', value: 8},{label: '1909', value: 9},{label: '1910', value: 10},
    {label: '1911', value: 11}, {label: '1912', value: 12}, {label: '1913', value: 13},{label: '1914', value: 14},{label: '1915', value: 15},
    {label: '1916', value: 16}, {label: '1917', value: 17}, {label: '1918', value: 18},{label: '1919', value: 19},{label: '1920', value: 20},
    {label: '1921', value: 21}, {label: '1922', value: 22}, {label: '1923', value: 23},{label: '1924', value: 24},{label: '1905', value: 25},
    {label: '1926', value: 26}, {label: '1927', value: 27}, {label: '1928', value: 28},{label: '1929', value: 29},{label: '1910', value: 30},
    {label: '1931', value: 31}, {label: '1932', value: 32}, {label: '1933', value: 33},{label: '1934', value: 34},{label: '1915', value: 35},
    {label: '1936', value: 36}, {label: '1937', value: 37}, {label: '1938', value: 38},{label: '1939', value: 39},{label: '1920', value: 40},
    {label: '1941', value: 41}, {label: '1902', value: 42}, {label: '1903', value: 43},{label: '1904', value: 44},{label: '1905', value: 45},
    {label: '1946', value: 46}, {label: '1907', value: 47}, {label: '1908', value: 48},{label: '1909', value: 49},{label: '1910', value: 50},
    {label: '1951', value: 51}, {label: '1902', value: 52}, {label: '1903', value: 53},{label: '1904', value: 54},{label: '1905', value: 55},
    {label: '1956', value: 56}, {label: '1907', value: 57}, {label: '1908', value: 58},{label: '1909', value: 59},{label: '1910', value: 60},
    {label: '1961', value: 61}, {label: '1902', value: 62}, {label: '1903', value: 63},{label: '1904', value: 64},{label: '1905', value: 65},
    {label: '1966', value: 66}, {label: '1907', value: 67}, {label: '1908', value: 68},{label: '1909', value: 69},{label: '1910', value: 70},
    {label: '1971', value: 71}, {label: '1902', value: 72}, {label: '1903', value: 73},{label: '1904', value: 74},{label: '1905', value: 75},
    {label: '1976', value: 76}, {label: '1907', value: 77}, {label: '1908', value: 78},{label: '1909', value: 79},{label: '1910', value: 80},
    {label: '1981', value: 81}, {label: '1902', value: 82}, {label: '1903', value: 83},{label: '1904', value: 84},{label: '1905', value: 85},
    {label: '1986', value: 86}, {label: '1907', value: 87}, {label: '1908', value: 88},{label: '1909', value: 89},{label: '1910', value: 90},
    {label: '1991', value: 91}, {label: '1902', value: 92}, {label: '1903', value: 93},{label: '1904', value: 94},{label: '1905', value: 95},
    {label: '1996', value: 96}, {label: '1907', value: 97}, {label: '1908', value: 98},{label: '1909', value: 99},{label: '1910', value: 100},
    {label: '2001', value: 101}, {label: '2002', value: 102}, {label: '2003', value: 103},{label: '2004', value: 104},{label: '2005', value: 105},
    {label: '2006', value: 106}, {label: '2007', value: 107}, {label: '2008', value: 108},{label: '2009', value: 109},{label: '2010', value: 110},
    {label: '2011', value: 111}, {label: '2012', value: 112}, {label: '2013', value: 113},{label: '2014', value: 114}
  ]

}).setValue('none', false);

var select2 = ui.Select({
  
  items: [{label: '------------------', value: 'none'}, {label: '1990', value: 0},
    {label: '1901', value: 1}, {label: '1902', value: 2}, {label: '1903', value: 3},{label: '1904', value: 4},{label: '1905', value: 5},
    {label: '1906', value: 6}, {label: '1907', value: 7}, {label: '1908', value: 8},{label: '1909', value: 9},{label: '1910', value: 10},
    {label: '1911', value: 11}, {label: '1912', value: 12}, {label: '1913', value: 13},{label: '1914', value: 14},{label: '1915', value: 15},
    {label: '1916', value: 16}, {label: '1917', value: 17}, {label: '1918', value: 18},{label: '1919', value: 19},{label: '1920', value: 20},
    {label: '1921', value: 21}, {label: '1922', value: 22}, {label: '1923', value: 23},{label: '1924', value: 24},{label: '1905', value: 25},
    {label: '1926', value: 26}, {label: '1927', value: 27}, {label: '1928', value: 28},{label: '1929', value: 29},{label: '1910', value: 30},
    {label: '1931', value: 31}, {label: '1932', value: 32}, {label: '1933', value: 33},{label: '1934', value: 34},{label: '1915', value: 35},
    {label: '1936', value: 36}, {label: '1937', value: 37}, {label: '1938', value: 38},{label: '1939', value: 39},{label: '1920', value: 40},
    {label: '1941', value: 41}, {label: '1902', value: 42}, {label: '1903', value: 43},{label: '1904', value: 44},{label: '1905', value: 45},
    {label: '1946', value: 46}, {label: '1907', value: 47}, {label: '1908', value: 48},{label: '1909', value: 49},{label: '1910', value: 50},
    {label: '1951', value: 51}, {label: '1902', value: 52}, {label: '1903', value: 53},{label: '1904', value: 54},{label: '1905', value: 55},
    {label: '1956', value: 56}, {label: '1907', value: 57}, {label: '1908', value: 58},{label: '1909', value: 59},{label: '1910', value: 60},
    {label: '1961', value: 61}, {label: '1902', value: 62}, {label: '1903', value: 63},{label: '1904', value: 64},{label: '1905', value: 65},
    {label: '1966', value: 66}, {label: '1907', value: 67}, {label: '1908', value: 68},{label: '1909', value: 69},{label: '1910', value: 70},
    {label: '1971', value: 71}, {label: '1902', value: 72}, {label: '1903', value: 73},{label: '1904', value: 74},{label: '1905', value: 75},
    {label: '1976', value: 76}, {label: '1907', value: 77}, {label: '1908', value: 78},{label: '1909', value: 79},{label: '1910', value: 80},
    {label: '1981', value: 81}, {label: '1902', value: 82}, {label: '1903', value: 83},{label: '1904', value: 84},{label: '1905', value: 85},
    {label: '1986', value: 86}, {label: '1907', value: 87}, {label: '1908', value: 88},{label: '1909', value: 89},{label: '1910', value: 90},
    {label: '1991', value: 91}, {label: '1902', value: 92}, {label: '1903', value: 93},{label: '1904', value: 94},{label: '1905', value: 95},
    {label: '1996', value: 96}, {label: '1907', value: 97}, {label: '1908', value: 98},{label: '1909', value: 99},{label: '1910', value: 100},
    {label: '2001', value: 101}, {label: '2002', value: 102}, {label: '2003', value: 103},{label: '2004', value: 104},{label: '2005', value: 105},
    {label: '2006', value: 106}, {label: '2007', value: 107}, {label: '2008', value: 108},{label: '2009', value: 109},{label: '2010', value: 110},
    {label: '2011', value: 111}, {label: '2012', value: 112}, {label: '2013', value: 113},{label: '2014', value: 114}
  ]

}).setValue('none', false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a hard time seeing a pattern in your labels/values. `1902` is for instance showing up a bunch of times. Assuming this is a mistake, and you want the value to be `year - 1900`, you could do like this:

```
var select1 = ui.Select({
  items: [{label: '------------------', value: 'none'}]
    .concat(yearOptions(1901, 2014))
}).setValue('none', false)

var select2 = ui.Select({
  items: [{label: '------------------', value: 'none'}]
    .concat(yearOptions(1901, 2014))
}).setValue('none', false)

print(select1, select2)


function yearOptions(startYear, endYear) {
  return sequence(startYear, endYear)
    .map(function (year) {
      return {
        label: '' + year,
        value: year - 1900
      }
    })
}

function sequence(start, end) {
  return Array.apply(null, {length: end - start + 1})
    .map(function (_, i) {
      return start + i
    })  
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8e1527f2e20a6f8c1563bb13674a0120

Comment: Thank you so much. I am almost close to the goal due to your answer. Yes, you're right. I wrong a mistake in my label/values. In addition, Could you teach me how to return the value in yearOption function to string like '1990'?